# NEST JS module register error with new connection

Tags: javascript, node.js, nestjs, nestjs-config

Hi im trying to create a new module with connected a new database, but its shows me an error:

```
//module    
@Module({
      imports: [CoffeesModule,
        DatabaseModule.register({ //  passing in dynamic values
          type: 'postgres',
          host: process.env.DATABASE_HOST, // database host
          port: +process.env.DATABASE_PORT, // database host
          username: process.env.DATABASE_USER, // username
          password: process.env.DATABASE_PASSWORD, // user password
          database: process.env.DATABASE_NAME, // name of our database,
        })],
      providers: [CoffeeRatingService]
    })
    export class CoffeeRatingModule { }

@Module({})
export class DatabaseModule {
  static register(options: ConnectionOptions): DynamicModule {
    return {
      module: DatabaseModule,
      providers: [
        {
          provide: 'CONNECTION', // 
          useValue: createConnection(options),
        }
      ]
    }
  }
};
```

But its show me

> (node:14394) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: error: password
> authentication failed for user "globant"
> at Parser.parseErrorMessage (/home/globant/repos/ilovecoffie/node_modules/pg-protocol/dist/parser.js:278:15)
> at Parser.handlePacket (/home/globant/repos/ilovecoffie/node_modules/pg-protocol/dist/parser.js:126:29)
> at Parser.parse (/home/globant/repos/ilovecoffie/node_modules/pg-protocol/dist/parser.js:39:38)
> at Socket. (/home/globant/repos/ilovecoffie/node_modules/pg-protocol/dist/index.js:8:42)
> at Socket.emit (events.js:314:20)
> at addChunk (_stream_readable.js:303:12)
> at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:279:9)
> at Socket.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:218:10)
> at TCP.onStreamRead (internal/stream_base_commons.js:188:23)

But the port and config settings to connection are right, because i already have a conection with type ORM:

```
@Module({
  imports: [
    ConfigModule.forRoot(),
    CoffeesModule,
    TypeOrmModule.forRoot({
      type: 'postgres', // type of our database
      host: process.env.DATABASE_HOST, // database host
      port: +process.env.DATABASE_PORT, // database host
      username: process.env.DATABASE_USER, // username
      password: process.env.DATABASE_PASSWORD, // user password
      database: process.env.DATABASE_NAME, // name of our database,
      autoLoadEntities: true, // models will be loaded automatically (you don't have to explicitly specify the entities: [] array)
      synchronize: true, // your entities will be synced with the database (ORM will map entity definitions to corresponding SQL tabled), every time you run the application (recommended: disable in the production)
    }),
    CoffeeRatingModule,
    DatabaseModule,],
  controllers: [
    AppController],
  providers: [AppService],
})
export class AppModule { }
```

And its working:

[image]

Comment: Does "createConnection(...)" return a promise? If so, you may need to switch "useValue: createConnection(options)" to "useFactory: async () => await createConnection(options)"

Comment: How do those options get passed to your database driver? Is it a wrapper on TypeORM? How does `process.env` get populated? I see you're using a `ConfigModule`, any reason you aren't using a `ConfigService` as well?

Comment: I guess the issue comes from NestJS official course. I had the same issue there. Thank you for the solution.